# What's with all the versions of sprintf in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Seriously, there seem to be dozens.  Is one more or less canonical?  How would I know?

Last year, I grabbed a version (not realizing it was one of many) and I actually made several improvements -- actually, two: the standard one of allowing named parameters, so `$.sprintf("Hi, %(username)s!", { username : localUsername } )`; and my own improvement of allowing object look-up, `$.sprintf("Hi, %(user.username)s!", { user : localUser } )` -- but when I went to send the changes back to the original author, he couldn't be found!

I'd like to use the *current* version of sprintf, so any pointers would help -- and from the teach-a-man-to-fish file, if you could tell me how you know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a "canonical" sprintf for jQuery. They are all custom plugins that have no official standing. My suggestion is to find the one you like best and use that throughout your project(s). If the one you prefer appears to be unmaintained you can probably just assume maintainership of it, if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

There is one of the javascript sprintf
http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sprintf.html
If you like to use q-n described style - there some template engine in latest jquery
also it included to phpjs library

Comment: My problem is, there are so many `sprintf` variations out there, my head is about to [asplode](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=asplode)!   Now you show up with one more!

Comment: to just confuse you more, there is currently supported js version of js and much more: http://phpjs.org